# Importing text files or compressed files in QlikView using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, qlikview

I have multiple text files in a folder. I need those files to be imported into QlikView on a daily basis. Is there any way to import those files using batch/command file?

Moreover, can I import compressed files into QlikView?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't edit it into your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following script checks whether qvd exists or not. If, yes then it update it otherwise create a new qvd

```
IF NOT isNull(qvdCreateTime('G:\TestQvd\Data.qvd')) THEN
   data2:
    load * from G:\TestQvd\Data.qvd(qvd);
    FOR each vFille in filelist ('G:\Test\*')                   
        LOAD * FROM
        [$(vFille)]
        (txt, codepage is 1252, explicit labels, delimiter is spaces, msq); 
         NEXT vFille   
 ELSE
    FOR each vFille in filelist ('G:\Test\*')   
     data2:                
        LOAD * FROM
        [$(vFille)]
        (txt, codepage is 1252, explicit labels, delimiter is spaces, msq); 
         NEXT vFille                   
 ENDIF 
        STORE data2 into G:\TestQvd\Data.qvd;    
   exit Script;
```

Comment: Even though this answer only answers the second part of the question, as you are not actually using a list of source files, but instead just loading everything in a folder you can use a wildcard load which simplifies things:

data2:
LOAD
    *
FROM [G:\Test\*] (txt, codepage is 1252, explicit labels, delimiter is spaces, msq); 

IF NOT isNull(qvdCreateTime('G:\TestQvd\Data.qvd')) THEN
data2:
LOAD
    *
FROM G:\TestQvd\Data.qvd(qvd);
ENDIF

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your load script is set up, but if you wish to refresh your QlikView document, and you don't have QlikView Server, then you can use a batch file as follows:

```
"<Path To QlikView>\QV.exe" /r "ReportToReload.qvw"
```

The `/r` command parameter tells QlikView to open the document, reload it and then save and close the document. However, you must make sure that the QlikView User Preference option "Keep Progress Open after Reload" is not enabled, otherwise the progress dialogue will wait for you to close it after the document has been reloaded.

You can then schedule this batch file to run via Windows' Task Scheduler, or your favourite scheduling tool.

QlikView cannot import compressed files (e.g. Zip/RAR etc.), so you would need to extract these first using a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your directory structure and read the existing files in your load script.

```
LET vCustCount = NoOfRows('Kunde');
TRACE Anzahl Kunden: $(vCustCount);

FOR i=1 TO $(vCustCount) 
    LET vNameKunde = FieldValue('name_kunde',$(i));
    FOR each vFile in filelist ('$(vNameKunde)/umsatz.qvd')
    TRACE $(vFile) hat eine umsatz.qvd;

        LOAD ....
         FROM [$(vFile)] (qvd);
    NEXT vFile 
NEXT
```

In this case I load pre-calculated qvd files but you could do the same with txt, csv ...

And as *i_saw_drones* mentioned QlikView cannot import compressed files. If you need to read compressed files you can batch operate them with a unzip tool.

You should have a look at
    21.1 Loading Data from Files
in the *Reference Manual*.

HTH

Comment: Can you look the script in my question. what's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, have no time now. You say: But it doesn't give the expected result. What result does it give? Try with a small amount of data and try to *TRACE* your output.